# Multipart passthrough in API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, file-upload, flask, multipart, aws-api-gateway

I have a web application that accepts multipart/form-data and have set up api gateway to pass through the requests to it. However, any time I upload images as part of the form they end up being larger than the original file I uploaded and corrupted. If I execute the same method without going via AWS API gateway the image uploads fine. Any ideas what I'm missing here?

the below is my S3 code that reads the form data in flask:

```
    f = request.files['attachment']
    fp = StringIO(f.read())
    file_uuid = str(uuid.uuid4())
    bucketkey.key = "att_%s%s" % (file_uuid, file_extension(f.filename))
    bucketkey.set_contents_from_file(fp)
```

I'll attach a link to a sample jpg that is corrupted if its useful at all.

https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/agendacommunities/att_ef7375b1-bb19-4df9-9162-5582ed66797c.jpeg

Comment: It's likely being Base64 encoded. Have you tried Base64 decoding it?

Comment: No luck unfortunately - unable to decode the file itself or the file contents. The other fields in the form is passed through correctly though which is puzzling. I would have thought the whole body was b64encoded but nein. thanks for the input though!

Comment: Have you tried *downloading* the "corrupted" images and reviewing the file contents with a hex editor?  There's one way for a file to become larger that should be self-explanatory if you examine what you've uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

What is your intent with StringIO?  f.read() will give you bytes, not a string.  I think you can pass f directly to set_contents_from_file and it will read from f.

```
f = request.files['attachment']
file_uuid = str(uuid.uuid4())
bucketkey.key = "att_%s%s" % (file_uuid, file_extension(f.filename))
bucketkey.set_contents_from_file(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set content-type header for your data to be recognized as binary by API Gateway.